# Haskell mongodb gridfs

Tags: mongodb, haskell, gridfs

Is there support for gridfs in haskell driver?

If not, would it be OK to store binary files without gridfs if they are under 16M?
All I need is to store some attachments like .txt .doc .xls .pdf .jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for gridfs in haskell mongodb driver. Actually  this driver development is currently frozen because of some internal problems, but new driver is under development now, and it will be support gridfs, but release is planned in some months.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the answer for the second part of the question? Would it be ok to store files under 16M without the gridfs?

Comment: Yes, looks like it quiet OK. There is only a possible problem with indices, i.e. it's not possible to index large fields.